# Programming bsxfun at CUDA via CUBLAS or THRUST?

Tags: matlab, cuda, thrust, cublas, bsxfun

I have a vector V that has nx1 items and a matrix M that has nxm item. I want to sum V with all the columns of M with CUDA. Is there any method in THRUST or CUBLAS that can help me to get away the problem?

Comment: Will there be a point where you will start reading the documentation for these libraries, or are you just going to keep asking naïve questions in the hope someone will do all your thinking for you? You already asked this question as part of your previous "port my Matlab code to CUDA" question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find row to all rows distance matrix between two matrices W and X in Thrust or Cublas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351981/how-can-i-find-row-to-all-rows-distance-matrix-between-two-matrices-w-and-x-in-t)

Answer (score 1):

Here What I've done with two down votes

```
thrust::device_vector<float> dummy_y(N,1);
alpha = 1.0f;
beta = 0.0f;
stat = cublasSger_v2(handle,K,N,&alpha,thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&dummy_y[0]),1,thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&A_sum_vec_d[0]),1,thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&C_d[0]),K);
```

I replicate the column vector by multiplying row vector, full of 1s, as in the size of matrix and sum with `cublasSger`. `stat` is keeping the execution status of the code and you may check for any possible error.

Comment: you shouldn't ever call any of the versioned API functions in your code. Call `cublasSger` not `cublasSger_v2`.